# How can I make my domain name display correctly in peoples web browsers?

Tags: dns, nameservers, punycode

I bought [http://jørgensens.com](http://j%C3%B8rgensens.com) but when I visit it in a browser it changes the name to http://xn--jrgensens-l8a.com/. How can I fix this so that it displays to everyone the name I wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The signal that it is a punycode string that should be decoded into Unicode and displayed accordingly to users is the `xn--` prefix. If an application doesn't treat that as intended, either because it's badly written or because it predates IDN in DNS, there is nothing you can do except send in a bug report for the application.

Comment: It displays correctly on iphone using safari browser, but chrome, android, and IE all display it incorrectly. So that it displays correctly in some browsers says that it should work? I mailed google (who I purchased the domain through....so far that's not helping....they have basically said "tough luck"....if it predates idn in dns then can I petition it that way?